# Terraform templatefile function - ssh config or ansible hosts files creation

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

Is it possible to create ssh config or ansible hosts files using terraform templatefile function?
Using Terraform 0.12.

Terraform definition:

```
resource "local_file" "ansible_hosts_file" {
    content = templatefile("templates/ansible_hosts.tpl", {
    jumphost_fip = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.dth_fip.address,
    node_name = module.app-cluster.app_cluster_compute.*.name,
    node_ip = module.app-cluster.app_cluster_compute.*.access_ip_v4
    })
    filename = "../config/inventory/hosts"
}

resource "local_file" "ssh_config_file" {
    content = templatefile("templates/ssh_config.tpl", {
    jumphost_fip = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.dth_fip.address,
    node_name = module.app-cluster.app_cluster_compute.*.name,
    node_ip = module.app-cluster.app_cluster_compute.*.access_ip_v4
    })
    filename = "../config/inventory/ssh_config"
}
```

My issue is that I have no idea how template files should look like, especially Interpolation or Directives..

ansible_hosts.tpl

```
jumphost ansible_host=${jumphost_fip}

[app_cluster]
%{ for node in node_name ~}        # ???????????? These 3 lines don't work of course
${node} ansible_host=${node_ip}    # ???????????? so could this be somehow specified
%{ endfor ~}                       # ???????????? that node and node_ip are filled in correctly?

[app_cluster:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args=' -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q jumphost"'

[all:vars]
ansible_user=ubuntu
```

ssh_config.tpl

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
Host jumphost
    Hostname ${jumphost_ip}
    User ubuntu
%{ for node in node_name ~}                   # ???????????? Similar issue here
Host ${node}                                  # ????????????
    Hostname ${node_ip}                       # ????????????
    User ubuntu
    ProxyCommand ssh -A jumphost -W %h:%p
%{ endfor ~}
```

The ansible hosts file and ssh config should look as follows:

ansible_hosts

```
jumphost ansible_host=10.200.100.100
 [app_cluster]
 app-node01 ansible_host=192.168.0.3
 app-node02 ansible_host=192.168.0.5
 [app_cluster:vars]
 ansible_ssh_common_args=' -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q jumphost"'
 [all:vars]
 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

ssh_config

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
 Host jumphost
     Hostname 10.200.100.100
     User ubuntu
 Host app-node01
    Hostname 192.168.0.3
    User ubuntu
    ProxyCommand ssh -A jumphost -W %h:%p
 Host app-node02
    Hostname 192.168.0.5
    User ubuntu
    ProxyCommand ssh -A jumphost -W %h:%p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[index] is the key for solution in template files:

ansible_hosts.tpl

```
%{ for index, node in node_name ~}
${node} ansible_host=${node_ip[index]}
%{ endfor ~}
```

ssh_config.tpl

```
%{ for index, node in node_name ~}
Host ${node}
    Hostname ${node_ip[index]}
    User ubuntu
    ProxyCommand ssh -A jumphost -W %h:%p
%{ endfor ~}
```

Source - https://www.linkbynet.com/produce-an-ansible-inventory-with-terraform